# Which control should I use to show post records from my database in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Which control should I use to show post records from my database in ASP.NET?

On my project page I would like to show recently featured projects. The number of projects can vary. I'm looking for a control like `GridView` or something that alter the properties of accordingly to get data from my database.

Below is an image of what I would like my page to look like:

[image: Posts]

I have been told to use `asp:ListView` but I don't know how to use it. Is this the right solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [GridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx)

> Displays the values of a data source in a table where each column
>   represents a field and each row represents a record. The GridView
>   control enables you to select, sort, and edit these items.

Or a [Repeater Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A data-bound list control that allows custom layout by repeating a
>   specified template for each item displayed in the list.

Comment: Thanks i used listview for this. it has more features than repeater.